# Defining a function using an Improper integral permitted?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, continuity, improper-integrals

Is it possible to define a function using an improper integral?

Here is an example of what I mean:

Suppose we have some $f: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ that is a well defined, monotonically decreasing function.

Let $F$ be a function such that:

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)dt$$

Would such a function definition be permitted.

If it is permitted am I also correct to assume that this function values can be calculated using the following method:
$$F(x) = \lim_{k \to -\infty} \int_{k}^{x}f(t)dt = \lim_{k \to -\infty}  f(x)\cdot x-f(k)\cdot k $$

My apologies in advanced for the simple question

Comment: Generally speaking yes, for example the 
complementary error function may be defined as  $$\operatorname{erfc}(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{-z}\exp(-t^2)\mathrm dt$$ Though, as shown in the answer below, your integral in this case will diverge.

Answer (score 1):

No, except for the zero function if you want to obtain real-valued function.

Assume that $f:\mathbb R \to [0,1]$ is monotonically decreasing and not equal $0$ everywhere. By assumption, there exist $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x_0) = \varepsilon > 0$. By monotonicity, for any $x < x_0$ we have $f(x) \geq \varepsilon$. That implies
$$
\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) \operatorname d \!t =
\int_{-\infty}^{x_0} f(t) \operatorname d \!t +
\int_{x_0}^x f(t) \operatorname d \!t
\geq 
\int_{-\infty}^x \varepsilon \operatorname d \!t +
\int_{x_0}^x f(t) \operatorname d \!t = \infty
$$
for any $x \in \mathbb R$.

If your initial function is zero everywhere, then $F$ is well defined and zero everywhere as well, so your formula checks out (but seems irrelevant to anything).